# How can i use two append in the same jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, append

I have a jQuery search function where I want to display at first an HTML block at the time I begin the search that shows the title "Search Result ". then I want to add another HTML block with id "entitiesNav" inside the first block with append. That's what I tried but it didn't work what can I do please?

```
<div id="searchRes>

    <div class="media post-block m-b-xs-30" id="entitiesNav">

          </div>

    </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var searchRequest = null;
            $("#search").keyup(function() {
                var minlength = 1;
                var that = this;
                var value = $(this).val();

                var searchResult = $("#searchRes").html('');
                var entitySelector = $("#entitiesNav").html('');
                if (value.length >= minlength ) {
                   searchResult.append('<section class="section-gap section-gap-top__with-text trending-stories" >' +
                        '<div class="container">\n' +
                        '            <div class="section-title m-b-xs-40">\n' +
                        '                <h2 class="axil-title">Search Result</h2>\n' +
                        '\n' +
                        '            </div>\n' +
                        '            <div class="row">\n' +
                        '            <div class="col-lg-6">'+'</div> <!-- End of .col-lg-6 -->\n' +
                       '\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n' +
                       '\t\t\t\t\t<!-- End of .row -->\n' +
                       '\t\t\t\t</div>\n' +
                       '\t\t\t\t<!-- End of .container -->\n' +
                       '\t\t\t</section>'

                   ) ;

                    if (searchRequest != null)
                        searchRequest.abort();
                    searchRequest = $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "{{ path('search_ajax') }}",
                        data: {
                            'q' : value
                        },
                        dataType: "text",
                        success: function(msg){
                            //we need to check if the value is the same
                            if (value===$(that).val()) {
                                var result = JSON.parse(msg);
                                $.each(result, function(key, arr) {
                                    $.each(arr, function(id, value) {
                                        if (key === 'articles') {
                                            if (id !== 'error') {
                                                console.log(value[1]);

                                                entitySelector.appendTo(searchResult).append('<a href="/show_article'+id+'">'+'<img class=" m-r-xs-30" src="'+value[0]+'" >'+'</a>'+'<h3 class="axil-post-title hover-line hover-line">'+value[1]+'</h3>');
                                            } else {
                                                entitySelector.append('<li class="errorLi">'+value+'</li>');
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Show what represent your` entityNav`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked your code. jQuery append can work as much times as you want, just your coding has some logical errors.

You are removing the element above and then you try to put elements in the removed one that does'not exist now.

[image]

[image]

You don't need to empty that searchRes.

Comment: If you want the element itself just remove .html(''). If you want element's html keep it like this .html(), without string signs.